# Add local package to composers autoload.php

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm working on a package that I later want to upload to packagist. But for now, I just want to develop it locally. But I can't find a way to have composer autoload my package without having it in Packagist.

Currently my project structure looks like this:

```
www/
  index.php
  composer.json
  composer.lock
  vendor/
    autoload.php
    acme/
      http/
        composer.json
        src/
          Request.php
```

I have manually placed my `acme` folder inside the `vendor` folder. I also added another `composer.json` inside the `acme/http` folder with the following contents:

```
{
    "name": "Acme/Http",
    "authors": [{
            "name": "Acme"
        }],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\Http\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how can I now add my "local" project to composers `autoload.php`?

Comment: I found a solution here after searching a lot : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30457277/5645769

Answer (score 3):

Would be much more clean and clear to have `acme/http` outside `vendor`:

```
www/
  index.php
  composer.json
  composer.lock
  acme/
    http/
      composer.json
      src/
        Request.php
  vendor/
    autoload.php
```

Then use a [`repositories`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) entry on the `www/composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "foo/www",
    ...
    "require": {
        "acme/http": "*",
        ..
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./acme/http"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader.

For more info see:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload

Comment: This options isn't working. The command doesn't display any errors, but it can't find my local classes either. I simply ran the command in my `www` directory.

Answer (score -2):

Add your class to `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` or `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

Comment: These file are frequently overwritten.